# Windows 7 professional.32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, permissions

I am trying to change directory on my command line in my C drive. I am trying to access python25 folder at C:/Python25/ but every time I write cd> C:/Python25/ and press enter, cmd returns Access is denied

My account is administrator.

I have read and execute permission for C:
I also tried to change directory to C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents
but still access is denied

Comment: This a local or domain user?

Comment: Why that `>` in `cd> C:/Python25/`? A typo only?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what you mean by that. More details would be appreciated

Comment: @JosefZ I thought that it was needed

Comment: Take a  look: [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try backslashes instead, and leave out the ">" as that does something entirely different and undesirable in this situation.

```
cd c:\Python25\
```

Comment: Glad it worked.  Would you mind marking it as an answer?